# Adding class library reference to asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have created asp.net core MVC application project. I added another core class library project in solution. Now I am trying to add reference of class library to MVC application but getting this error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The following projects are not supported as references :

- Mylibrary.Service has target frameworks that are incompatible with targets in current project Mylibrary.Web.

Mylibrary.Web:

```
.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
```

Mylibrary.Service:

```
.NETStandard,Version=v1.6
```

**[UPDATE]**

Web project project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },


"frameworks": {      
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and service project project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Clicon.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "Clicon.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {   
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried changing the target framework of the projects so that they both target the same framework?

Comment: add `project.json` from both projects web and library in question.

Comment: @Ahmar Please check updated question with project.json files.

Comment: change framework import to this in web project. you already added it dependencies section.


 "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: @Ahmar I did but same error

Comment: try to update your asp.net core version to 1.1